# Testng Parallel stops execution of one browser when other browser starts

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, selenium, testng

My test case runs in 2 browsers - IE and Firefox. When run the test, it opens IE and starts executing the test. But once firefox is opened, IE browser does not execute the test. It stops abruptly throwing Testng failure message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Following is my XML

```
<parameter name="browser" value ="Firefox"/>

    <classes>

        <class name = "testng.testsuite1"/>

    </classes>
```

```
<parameter name="browser" value ="IE"/>

    <classes>


        <class name = "testng.testsuite1"/>

    </classes>
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: you're propably using the same webdriver instance for both cases? post your source-code where you start the relevant drivers.

Comment: try{ 
    if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){
   

       System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "c://ie//IEDriverServer.exe");
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
     
     }
     

   else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
   {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } 
   
   }
   catch(WebDriverException e)

   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

You are using same driver in both the cases, that why when second execution starts, driver is re-initialized ans hence IE execution stops. 
Try creating separate driver instances for both browsers.

```
try{ if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){ 
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "c://ie//IEDriverServer.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
} else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) { 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
} 
} catch(WebDriverException e) {
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} 
}
```

Comment: I want to run the same test script in both the browsers simultaneously. Sorry if I have missed that point in my question. Is there any other way to execute the tests parallely

Comment: Yes...just write common code in one method which takes webdriver as an argument. Then just pass this driver as a parameter to this method.

Comment: sorry for my late reply. It dint work.                                                           I have another question about testng. After execution of each test cases, results are stored in separated excel file along with test case id, test step, result of the test run and reason for failed test step. If I run the testcase in testng, I am not seeing these results. Instead it creates  an empty file which is not openable. I need the excel file with all details to check which step failed and why. Any insight about this...?